# Passing variable as argument to getByText from react testing library does not work

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

If you pass string literal to getByText from react testing library it works fine

```
getByText('my text')
```

but if you pass same string as variable it finds nothing

```
const text: string = 'my text'
getByText(text) // this returns no match even though with literal it worked fine
```

what could be the problem?

```
test('page displays users activities on load', async () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    const {getByText} = render(
        <Router history={history}>
            <Dashboard />
        </Router>
    )

    await waitFor(() => getByText("Programovanie v jazyku C", {exact: false}))

    activityData.forEach((activity) => {
        expect(getByText(activity.title, {exact: false})).toBeTruthy()
    })
})
```

Edit: Added my code

Component dashboard contains tables, which are populated from mock api. Mock api data is same data as `activityData`. Wait for is called with string literal, title of first item of activityData. That works fine. But it doesnt work, whan called with variable.

Comment: It should work fine, could you post more details of your test suite ?

Comment: Edited question to include my code. When variable is used error is "    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Programovanie v jazyku C. This...." But as you see in code, when i use string literal "Programovanie v jazyku C" it works fine

Comment: Thanks you for the update. Could you try to reproduce in a codesandbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in data that i was passing through my mock service. It was copied from chrome console and after copying it contained characters in form "\8ief2", which on console print seemed as normal characters and probably in html too, but in reality weren't. Always check your data.